# Can I omit return from main in C?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, c99

In C++, 3.6.1 Main function

> (3.6.1/5) A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling exit with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches
>   the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is
>   that of executing return 0;**

Can I do the following in C99 without return 0?

```
int main() { }
```

Comment: You have a C++ standard but not a C standard?

Comment: @CarlNorum: Don't they both cost money?

Comment: @NPE: C99 Standard is freely avalaible online. And possible duplicate that also answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/1202636

Comment: Drafts are free.  Google "C99 PDF", and it's the first hit.

Comment: @NPE: the released standard costs money in both cases (at least for a legitimate copy). In either case, drafts almost indistinguishable from the real standard are available for free.

Comment: @NPE: actually I can easily find free PDFs of all major revisions of C and C++ standard except for C89 (just found a plain ASCII draft...), sometimes they are draft, but they are the same as the real standard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, as of C99, reaching the `}` at the end of main returns 0 if the return type of `main` is compatible with `int`.

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the C99 standard says (§5.1.2.2.3):

> reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.