# Works fine in C++, but runtime error in C

Tags: c++, c

I have this code here ::

```
int f(int x, int *py, int **ppz)
{
  int y, z;
  **ppz += 1; 
   z  = **ppz;
  *py += 2;
   y = *py;
   x += 3;
   return x + y + z;
}

int main()
{
   int c, *b, **a;
   c = 4;
   b = &c;
   a = &b; 
   printf( "%d\n", f(c,b,a));
   printf( "%d\n", c);
}
```

(Please choose the header files accordingly)

When I run this code as a C++ program, it runs smoothly. But, when I run it as a C program, it completes its execution, prints all the values, but on the last line of the code, gives a Runtime Error.
I attached a debugger, and at the end of the program(while running this code in C) on clicking Step-Over, it takes me to a min_gw file, which looks something like this::

```
__mingw_CRTStartup()
__mingw_CRTStartup+208: mov    %eax,%ebx
__mingw_CRTStartup+210: call   0x407fb0 <_cexit>
__mingw_CRTStartup+215: mov    %ebx,(%esp)
__mingw_CRTStartup+218: call   0x408088 <ExitProcess@4>
__mingw_CRTStartup+223: nop
```

What is this file?? And why does the code fail in C??

*Ideone references ::*

C :: http://ideone.com/sDbqnI

C++ :: http://ideone.com/Ubb71k

Thanks for any help in advance.. :)

Comment: Both programs are fine. Ideone reports runtime error because your `main` reaches the end without returning a value.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no, it's UB to fall off the end (and use the value, which the runtime does).

Comment: dasblinkenlight: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545291/can-i-omit-return-from-main-in-c

Comment: @amaurea Why, there are two answers like that already :-)

Comment: @Olaf No, it is completely defined for main.

Comment: @this: Yeah, just read in the standard. `main()` is a special case (I hate such unnecessary exceptions). Well, my `main()`s are mostly `void` anyway.

Comment: @Olaf `void main` is never allowed.

Comment: @o11c: gotcha - be careful with absolute statements;-). Read about [freestanding environments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1). There is no reqirement for a special `main()` - it could be called whatever you want and have any signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All versions of C++, and C since C99, add an implicit `return 0;` at the end of main before falling off the end.

C89 (which is the default for most compilers) does not, so it is UB if you actually return from main by falling off the end.

Edit: In practice (assuming you are running without sanitizers), this means that you will return whatever happens to be in `$eax` already, i.e. the return value of the last function. Since `printf` usually returns a non-zero value, that is treated as failure.

Comment: As I understand, as of the C99 standard, this is added implicitly in C as well.

Comment: @wjl 5.1.2.2.3, yeah.

Comment: You should add C11 to the list.

Comment: Thank you so much.. That was indeed a dumb error. But, I tried inserting an empty `printf` statement at the end of the program, so that it returns `0` but, It still gives the runtime error

Comment: @user007 Likely `-fsanitize=ubsan` catches it regardless.

Comment: @user007: Not sure if that helps, but: MSVC does not comply to C99 (not to talk about C11).

Comment: @Olaf probably Netbeans doesn't either.. Thanks though :)

Comment: @user007: Don't worry, I didn't know either that the standard requires `main()` to properly terminate even without explicit `return`. Just always use it and you are on the safe side.

Comment: @user007 Netbeans is not a compiler, just an IDE. It usually just calls `gcc`.

Comment: @o11c: Interesting sidenote: gcc actually _does_ complain when using `-Wall` for a freestanding environment, but not for a hosted - the default for non-crosscompilation. Reason is likely, there is no requirement for a special `main()` by the standard.

Comment: Note that the current standard is C11. Earlier standards have been withdrawn, so talking about "standard" means C11. gcc for instance does use C11 as default now (5.1); it has been C90/89 before, however.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement in the end of main indicating success.

Comment: That would be `return 0`. This is automatically done for `main()`. No actual need for that.